# How to avoid looped Pentaho job logging "Finished job entry" rows multiple times?

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have created looped Pentaho(v8.1) job, It circles in every 15 seconds and entire job works about 7 minutes, but after 5 or 6 minutes I get thousands of similar rows in log field with texts  : "Finished job entry"
[image]

like this

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [Table input 3] (result=[true])
2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [Simple evaluation duration] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [SET PROCESS_STATUS 0] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [SEND CLIENTS&ACCOUNTS] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [FILL ALL  ACCOUNTS] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [Wait for] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [SET PROCESS_STATUS 2] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [call procedure] (result=[true])

2019/03/28 11:47:49 - FILLALLACC_MAIN_WF - Finished job entry [SET PROCESS_STATUS 1] (result=[true])
...

How can I avoid logging this looped "Finished job entry" rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try "Minimal" or "Error" log level when starting the job.

Otherwise, there's no way to suppress these messages. These are simply telling you what's going on in your job loops.

Comment: Log level is Error but it doesnot help, also I have not so many "Finished job entry" steps (thousands in a second).

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's an option to remove that logging. Can you clarify why you don't want those messages to appear? Is it impacting performance or functionality in some way?

Comment: Because after these thousands of similar logs I got error message Java.lang.StackOverflowError and log file get more than 1GB and after that pentaho server hangs and need to restart and delete log/pdi.txt log file.